# Safari Reader Ignoring H1 tag

Tags: html, safari

When the title in a `H1` tag is less then a certain amount of width it will be ignored by Safari reader. Have you noticed? As such, `<h1>Contact</h1>` will be ignored. Does anyone have a good work around for this?

Comment: Do you have some example? What reader in safari? You mean browser?

Comment: No, the OP is talking about the Safari browser and its Reader feature.

http://www.apple.com/safari/whats-new.html#gallery-read-reader

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the best article to help with the issue you are facing with. http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader

Safari reader has some algorithms to understand and categorize the content. Please go through the article. It has some experiments for some issues similar to yours.

Rgds.

Answer (score 0):

What if you added some `&nbsp;`'s after the title?  Or is it too smart for that?

(I know it's ugly)